# Can't create Unique index on loopback auto-migrate()

Tags: model, loopbackjs

I try to create Mysql Unique index on simple model with loopback automigrate, 
using defined models in JSON.

When i try add index in property part of model

```
myitem.json
{
  "name": "MyItem",
  "plural": "myitems",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },

  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
       "index":{"unique":true} //HERE
    }
  }
```

node throws this error

```
 [Error: ER_TOO_LONG_KEY: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes]
  code: 'ER_TOO_LONG_KEY',
  errno: 1071,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
```

I use InnoDB utf8_general_ci.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `"length":255` or less, to property solved it.